# Get distributed query data from Ignite local caches in cluster

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I have Ignite cache with name "IgniteCache" on each node in cluster(of 2 servers) with local mode enabled. Certain number of entries are loaded into these local caches. Now, I have started separate client node which queries data from this "IgniteCache" on cluster. But always when I query data, I am getting null result(Instead of getting data from both server nodes)

Comment: Please provide more details: how do you query the data? Can you verify that data is in cache by some other means (e.g. cache.get())?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because local caches are not distributed across nodes. When you query a local cache, you only will see data which is stored locally on the same node. You don't have any on the client, so result is empty.